# Flutter simultaneous images upload

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, file-upload, upload, dart-isolates

I need to upload a list of images into a storage, but I don't want to upload and await for every single image after the other, because it takes quite some time.
I would like to upload them simultaneously, like in different threads.
There is a way to do achieve multithreading with standard dart async? Or should I use Isolates?
Do you have some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can  use them in a single future

```
final results = await Future.wait([
  uploadFunction(image1)
  uploadFunction(image2)

]);
```

you can start uploading all images without waiting for the previous one to complete await will be returned once both uploads are completed

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Queue](https://pub.dev/packages/queue)

Whats it will do it will **hold your actions** and you can do other task while uploading images

```
import 'package:dart_queue/dart_queue.dart';

main() async {
  final queue = Queue(parallel: 2);

  
  final result1 = await queue.add(()=>Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10)));
  final result2 = await queue.add(()=>Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10)));

  //Thats it!
}
```

By using this you dont need to add **await**.

NOTE: Make sure app is running while this queue is active.

Comment: It seems that this library just allows me to queue futures and execute them one after the other, it does not execute them simultaneously. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right but for the image uploading, i suggest you to use it to avoid await.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this can help me.
I need to await for the upload, but I want to speed up the process by uploading simultaneously using different threads.

Comment: Okay, Keep growing !